# XPath to text returning nothing?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to address the text `Aug 7, 2019 at 9:34 am ET` in the following code with XPath:

```
<span class="meta"><span class="authordata">
<a href="https://example.com" title="Posts by me" rel="author">Author</a></span> | Aug 7, 2019 at 9:34 am ET
</span>
```

I use this Xpath expressions `//span[@class="meta"]/text()` , which always worked for me in such cases - but fail and get just emptyness.

I tried some variants too, like `//span[@class="meta"]/text[0]` and `//span[@class="meta"]/text[1]` - but failed too.

What could be the correct Xpath to `Aug 7, 2019 at 9:34 am ET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `//span[@class="meta"]/text()` is not returning what you want, then there may be a text node, perhaps containing only whitespace, *before* your targeted text.  (That expression will return all text node children of the targeted `span`, but in XPath 1.0 as an argument to a function requiring a string, only the first node of a node set is used.)

Since you probably don't want the preceding  `|` anyway, you might try calling `substring-after` on the string value of the parent element...

This XPath 1.0 expression,

```
substring-after(//span[span/a/@rel="author"],' |')
```

will evaluate to

```
Aug 7, 2019 at 9:34 am ET
```

as requested.

Comment: How should look this expression to match multiple elements on page? Page example is https://searchengineland.com/page/2?s=google+test - there are article publishing dates.

Comment: Use `substring-after(//span[span/a/@rel="author"][1],' |')` for first, `[2]` for second, etc.  If you can use XPath 2.0, then `//span[span/a/@rel="author"]/substring-after(.,' |')` will return a list containing all of the targeted timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
//span[@class="authordata"]/../text[1]
```

OR

```
//span[@class="meta"]/text()
```

After selecting the element locator stategy which is `//span[@class="meta"]` then invoke another node that's text nodes `/text()` and get the desired text value

[example](http://xpather.com/NCkDe7md)

Comment: XPather is bad place to test XPaths because it fails to implement the XPath Recommendation properly.   Here's [an example](http://xpather.com/VVjcwTXM) of entirely wrong behavior, which appears to show that your XPath would work if the source changed in a certain way but would actually fail with conformant XPath processors.